# What is VideoView's equivalent of MediaPlayer.reset in Android

Tags: android-videoview

I have application with VideoView in a activity (not the main activity). Sometimes VideoView freezes when it reaches end of media. When it happens VideoView does not play other media when the same activity is started again, no sound, no video, just background color.
Is there a way to reinitialize the VideoView like it was never used, without restarting the application ? I believe MediaLayer.reset can do that, although I did not try it yet.

Regards, Martin

Update: now the issue seems to be related to loss of wifi signal.

Comment: use `videoView.start();`

Comment: Kishore Jethava: thanks. Your answer is corrent to my question because my question was wrong. I was intersted in recreating of VideoView widget in some error conditions. Finishing the whole activity did not help, maybe because Android caches activities. Only restart of whole application helps.

Comment: did you solved?

Comment: No, I did not. I thought that something was wrong with VideoView but now I think it was all about wi-fi. Unfortunetaly I still do not know how to make VideoView work after wi-fi regains signal.